# Iterator in java.util.Map

Tags: java, dictionary, iterator

Created a simple java application with a Map to store some data and then iterate and print the key value.

```
Map<String,String> myMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
    myMap.put("1", "1");
    myMap.put("2", "2");
    myMap.put("3", "3");
    myMap.put("4", "4");

    Iterator<String> it1 = myMap.keySet().iterator();
    while(it1.hasNext()){
        String key = it1.next();
        System.out.println("Map key: "+key + "    Map Value:"+myMap.get(key));
       /* if(key.equals("2")){
            myMap.put("1","4");
            //myMap.put("4", "4");
        }*/
    }
```

Even I tried the change the put method with different combination like

```
    myMap.put("4", "4");
    myMap.put("1", "1");
    myMap.put("3", "3");
    myMap.put("2", "2");
```

But I couldn't understood why my program always display the first 3 object in descending. I couldn't trace what sequencing the iterator uses..

```
Map key: 3    Map Value:3
Map key: 2    Map Value:2
Map key: 1    Map Value:1
Map key: 4    Map Value:4
```

Comment: Read the last sentence of the first paragraph of the javadoc of HashMap: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html: *This class makes no guarantees as to the order of the map*

Comment: -1 for not reading the javadoc for HashMap.

Answer (score 2):

The order in which you'll receive elements from a `HashMap` is not guaranteed.  The only guarantees that it makes is that every insertion of a duplicate item is rejected (thus, leaving you with a collection of unique items).

If you want *both* guarantees, you'll want to use a `LinkedHashMap` instead, which guarantees insertion order.

Answer (score 1):

HashMap does not gurantee ordering of elements

Use [LinkedHashMap(entry order)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) or [TreeMap (sorted order)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) if ordering is requrired.

Answer (score 0):

Because `HashMap` use `Hashing` function for storing elements..  order is decide by Hashing function..
In simple word `Hasing` function return memory place where element well be store.

for more detail [click](http://howtodoinjava.com/2012/10/09/how-hashmap-works-in-java/)